# How to pass None or blank or multiple data types in Examples table in Python Behave

Tags: python-3.x, gherkin, python-behave

I'm new to Python- Behave and I'm now stuck so need your help. I have a scenario outline with examples table and I want to perform both positive and negative test so I want to pass None or different data types for the column. For e.g.

```
Scenario Outline:
Given I have <text> different scenarios with <sample> parameter

Examples:
| text | Sample |
| 5    | 33     |
| a    |        |
|      | abc    |
```

Now when I pass nothing then I'm not able to execute the step. Could you please help.

I tried the below code:

```
@parse.with_pattern(r"\w+")
def parse_string(text):
    return text.strip()

register_type(Val=parse_string)
use_step_matcher("cfparse")

@given(u'I have {text:Val?} different scenarios with {sample:Val?} 
parameter')
def step_impl(context, text, sample):
   context.text = text
   context.sample = sample
```

but the above code works only if I use the register type with only one parameter i.e. either for text or sample. If I use it for both then I'm getting an error that step is not implemented.

If you can please suggest me a better way then I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, this is a simple fix! Notice the parameter variables used in the given step:

```
Given I have <text> different scenarios with <sample> parameter
```

The second parameter variable `sample` is lowercase. However, the title of the Example table's second column is `Sample`, which is uppercase. These must be identical. Change `Sample` to `sample`, and the test should run successfully!

Here's what the output looked like on my machine:

```
$ behave --tags @temp
Feature: Temp Test # features/unit.feature:1

  @temp
  Scenario Outline:  -- @1.1                             # features/unit.feature:13
    Given I have 5 different scenarios with 33 parameter # features/steps/unit.py:22 0.001s

  @temp
  Scenario Outline:  -- @1.2                           # features/unit.feature:14
    Given I have a different scenarios with  parameter # features/steps/unit.py:22 0.000s

  @temp
  Scenario Outline:  -- @1.3                             # features/unit.feature:15
    Given I have  different scenarios with abc parameter # features/steps/unit.py:22 0.000s

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 2 skipped
3 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 19 skipped
3 steps passed, 0 failed, 57 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.002s
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew for answering but Sample was a typo and I fixed it earlier. Thanks for pointing it out. The problem I'm facing is if I pass blank or None and I get an error that the step is not implemented. I'm not sure how the last one worked for you. I'll look at it again.

Comment: Andrew, Is there a way to send the Examples from any file? Excel, yaml or a Json?